# Constraint, Reference to other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to do a constraint which will check that data in table1 cannot be earlier that data table2. eg.

```
Table1   
ID    Date
1     2015-05-06
2     2015-05-07
3     2015-05-08

Table2
    ID     ID2     Date
    434     1     2015-05-05
    435     2     2015-05-06
    436     3     2015-05-07

Table1 join Table2 on table1.ID=table2.id2
```

Now I would like to do alter table1 with constraint, how it would looks like?

Comment: It would look like trigger on table2

Comment: I can't do that by using check clause? Of course I need that check during inserting data

Comment: Is there a one to one relationship between table1 and table2? What are the primary and foreign keys for each table?

Comment: @maciek2791 no, you can't use check constraint here, because you can't use subquery in check constraint. So you need before insert trigger

Comment: Primary key for table 1 id ID and it refrence to Table2 ID2. Primary key of Table2 is ID. Ok then, so I have to use trigger. Ok thanks ; )

Comment: that means that `id2 is unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Primary key for table 1 id ID and it refrence to Table2 ID2. Primary key of Table2 is ID

From your own description in the your data-model looks like this:

```
create table t2 (
   id number
 , id2 number
 , dt date
 , constraint pk_t2 primary key (id)
 , constraint uk_t2_id2 unique (id2)
    );

insert into t2 values (434, 1, date '2015-05-05');
insert into t2 values (435, 2, date '2015-05-06');
insert into t2 values (436, 3, date '2015-05-07');

create table t1 ( 
   id number
 , dt date
 , constraint pk_t1 primary key (id)
 , constraint fx_t1_t2 foreign key (id)
    references t2 (id2)
   );

insert into t1 values (1, date '2015-05-06');
insert into t1 values (2, date '2015-05-07');
insert into t1 values (3, date '2015-05-08');
```

As the the common key (`t2.id2` and `t1.id`) is unique in both tables the way to enforce this constraint is to merge the two tables and add the constraint.

Your data model is equivalent to:

```
create table t1 (
   id number
 , id2 number
 , date1 date
 , date2 date
 , constraint pk_t1 primary key (id)
 , constraint uk_t1 unique (id2)
 , constraint chk_t1_dates 
     check (date1 < date2)
   );

insert into t1 values (434, 1, date '2015-05-05', date '2015-05-06');
insert into t1 values (435, 2, date '2015-05-06', date '2015-05-07');
insert into t1 values (436, 3, date '2015-05-07', date '2015-05-08');
```

There is no actual need for `id2`...

If you then need the data to be separate you can create two views to represent the tables

```
SQL> create or replace view v_t1 as
  2  select id2 as id, date1
  3    from t1;

View created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace view v_t2 as
  2  select id, id2, date2
  3    from t1;

View created.

SQL> select * from v_t1;

        ID DATE1
---------- ----------
         1 2015-05-05
         2 2015-05-06
         3 2015-05-07

SQL> select * from v_t2;

        ID        ID2 DATE2
---------- ---------- ----------
       434          1 2015-05-06
       435          2 2015-05-07
       436          3 2015-05-08
```